# Is there a possibility to reference another class via value object

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-xml-mapping

How can I make a many-to-one xml mapping from the stayId of RoomOccupancy to the stayId of Stay. Note that StayId is a value object, therefore it does not contain the whole reference to Stay.

```
 public class RoomOccupancy {
// generated hibernate id
private Long id;
private LocalDate startDate;
private LocalDate endDate;
private StayId stayId;
}


public class Stay {
// generated hibernate id
private Long id;
private StayId stayId;
}
```

I would be very glad, if someone could help me out.Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you, then you need make it like this:

```
public class RoomOccupancy {
private Long id;
private LocalDate startDate;
private LocalDate endDate;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Stay .class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stayId")
    private Stay stay;
}    

public class Stay {
private Long id;
}
```

Or if you need as xml, just add next code to your xml file

```
<many-to-one name = "stay" column = "stayId" class="Stay " not-null="true"/>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. Could you please write it down as a xml mapping, because I do not use annotations

Comment: If I thought right, just add <many-to-one name = "stay" column = "stayId" 
         class="Stay " not-null="true"/>  to your xml